# mysql How to select an ID when it's values are equal to X

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

I have tried quite a lot of solutions and I decided to post it here to try and find a solution. Any little help is welcome (so I can learn too).

I have a table formed by ArticleID, UserID, and Votes `(1/-1)`. 
I want to select the ArticleID that contains a certain UserID and which SUM of Votes is equal to 1.

So far I arrived to:

```
SELECT catch.ID, votes.postid, catch.text, votes.userid, votes.value, catch.name FROM catch INNER JOIN votes ON catch.ID=votes.postid AND votes.userid=:iduser AND votes.value='1' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 100
```

but this gives me an erroneous result, as it doesn't consider articles that have `votes 1 and -1` (which `SUM should be 0`).

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
ID + Value + userid 
1 | 1 | 54 
1 | -1 | 54 
3 | 1 | 54 
7 | 1 | 56 
7 | -1 | 56
```

Given the above table, and selecting just the user '54' the wanted result should be ID 3.

Comment: Could you please share some sample data for both tables and the result you're trying to get for that sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT c.ID, v.postid, c.text, v.userid, v.value, c.name
FROM catch c INNER JOIN
     votes v
     ON c.ID = v.postid AND v.userid = :iduser 
GROUP BY c.ID
HAVING SUM(v.value) = 1;
```

This is what you describe but it is a bit different from your query.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon , this made the trick. and I also got to learn the Group by, Having, and shorten the table!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, but for :iduser set what particular id of user

```
SELECT catch.ID, 
       votes.postid, 
       catch.text, 
       votes.userid, 
       SUM(votes.value), 
       catch.name 
FROM catch 
LEFT JOIN  votes ON catch.ID=votes.postid
WHERE votes.userid = :iduser and votes.value='1'
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Hi, the code I posted, is already working but is just returning all the ID which value is 1. What I would like (but I am failing at) is getting the ID which SUM of Value is = 1. I have updated my comment with an example. Thanks!

Comment: @Giona hey i edited what you want, just add sum at votes.value, and in where clause add for votes.userId, that must work

Comment: thanks for the above, but it is not giving the wanted result. I think it should group the ID